# Retain nested form field value after failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and have not yet managed to solve the following issue. I use devise for authentication with a model called "user". This model is associated to another model called "company":

**user.rb**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

  attr_accessible :company_attributes, :email, :password, 
                  :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :company_id
```

**company.rb**

```
  class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

On registration, a user creates both a company and a user:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_company

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user 
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The registration works out so far, meaning that if `@user.save` is true, two records are create each in the user and the company model with the correct association in the column `company_id` in the user model.

If `@user.save` is false, for instance because the validation for the user attribute email fails because it has already been taken, a new view is rendered. As expected, the `@user` attribute, in this case email, is retained and remains in the respective form field after `render action: 'new'`. The form field for the company attribute name, however, appears blank. This is the view for the registration page:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, 
                              :url => registration_path(resource_name),
                              :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :company,  @user.build_company do |builder| %>
        <div><%= builder.label :name, "Company" %><br />
        <%= builder.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, 
                            :placeholder => "Example Company Inc.",
                            :required => true %></div>
    <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "example@email.com",  :required => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password,  :required => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,  :required => true %></div>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => "btn"%>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I thought that I might have to create an instance variable `@company` in the user create method so that the form field content can be saved within the params hash like this:

```
@company = @user.build_company(params[:company])
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and so far I have not found a solution in other questions posted on stackoverflow. I am looking forward to your input so that i can proceed building my first app ;)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That may not be the reason but you use simple_form_for resource, yet fields_for :company. Try changind fields_for -> simple_fields_for and check it out!

Comment: Hey Michal, thanks for your quick response. I have just changed `f.fields_for`to `f.simple_fields_for`. Unluckily, the company name field will be rendered blank after validation fail.

Comment: Change this line `<%= f.simple_fields_for :company,  @user.build_company do |builder| %>` to `<%= f.simple_fields_for :company do |builder| %>`

Comment: Also I'm suspecting that Devise is messing up something in here/ Unfortunately I have no own code with this kind of relation (only User has_many other objects created in one form at signup). Maybe try to divide it into two separate forms and load second one in-place with ajax?

Comment: changing that line does not solve the issue either. However, the company name field won't render. So I assume that the line `@user.build_company`in my `new`method within the users_controller.rb does not create an instance of company within which the name attribute can be saved. Does that makes sense?

Comment: If company name field does not render it means that there's no associated Company object. That may confirm my suspicion that Devise drops associated model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michal's input, I rearranged my controllers so that a user will be created through an associated company and not the other way round. The respective company controller looks like this:

**companies_controller.rb**

```
# GET company/new
def new
    @company = Company.new
    @company.users.build
end

# POST company/
def create
    @company = Company.new(params[:company])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Welcome! Your account has been created successfully. A confirmation link has been sent to your email address.' }
        format.json { render json:  root_path, status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

The form the GET request nests the Devise User model fields as follows:

**new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Create an account</h2>
<%= simple_form_for( @company, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => @company %>
    <%= f.input     :name, 
                    :label =>'Company name',
                    :placeholder => "Example Company Inc.",
                    :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :users do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.input   :email, 
                            :placeholder => "example@email.com" %>
        <%= builder.input :password %>
        <%= builder.input :password_confirmation %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button    :submit, 'Create account',
                    :class => 'btn'%>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(:user) %>
```

Now, if the validation fails, all instance attribute values remain in their respective form field.